# Having trouble with creating/using a collection in MongoDB and PyMongo. Not sure what I'm doing wrong

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to create a small script that allows a user to login and register using Pymongo and MongoDB. I'm trying to use the 'Pinnacle' database and use/create a collection called 'Users' but i seem to be having problems. when i run
`use pinnacle`
in the mongodb shell it outputs `switched to db pinnacle`. Then I run 
`db.collection_names` and it just says `pinnacle.collection_names`. This leads me to believe that I'm getting some kind of error in my code while creating or using the collection. Here's my code:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import sys
import os
import time
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt
import pprint

client = MongoClient()


def login():
    loginUsername = input('Please input username to be signed in.')
    loginPassword = input('Please input password to be signed in.')


def registerAccount():
    registerUsername = input('Please input a username to be registered into our database.')
    registerPassword = input('Please input a password to be entered into our database.')
    passwordHash = sha256_crypt.hash(registerPassword)

    regDetails = {
        "username": registerUsername,
        "password": registerPassword,
        "passwordhash": passwordHash
    }

    db = client.pinnacle
    users = db.users
    users.insert(regDetails)
    # db.users.insert(regDetails)
    for a in db.users.find():
        pprint.pprint(a)


def checkRegistered():
    print('Coming soon')


def quit():
    os.system('clear')
    print('Closing...')
    time.sleep(3)
    sys.exit()


def menu():
    print('''
    1. Login
    2. Register new user
    3. Check number of people registered in the database
    4. Quit

    Select an option.
            ''')
    options = {'1': login, '2': registerAccount, '3': checkRegistered, '4': quit}
    options[input()]()


while True:
    menu()
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the shell, you can list the collections in the current database with:

```
db.getCollectionNames()
```

Not `db.collection_names`.

In Python, do:

```
db.collection_names()
```

Note the parentheses: this is a function call, not a property.